# Detect built-in drawing tablets buttons in Electron JavaScript

Tags: javascript, keyboard, electron

I got a new drawing tablet and it has some built-in buttons on the side.
[Huion h610 pro v2 drawing tablet with built in buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgisj.png)

How would I detect when a user presses one of these special buttons using ElectronJs?